# React - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs, meteor, ecmascript-6

Normally  When i click on the menu item in the child component it calls {this.handlesort} which is a local function. Handle sort takes in onReorder props from my parent component. {onReorder} calls a local function called reOrder. It sets the state of {orderBy and orderDir}. The problem is that immediately when i click on {menuitem} it returns this error. (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onReOrder' of undefined). Normally it works when i am not using es6. Please help

**(Parent Component)**

```
export default class TenantView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //setting state
        this.state = {
            //tenants: [],
            orderBy: 'name',
            orderDir: 'asc',};
    };
    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            tenants:[{img: 'tenant1.jpg',name: 'John', address: '7 Gilbert', 
                     paid: 'true'},{img: 'tenant2.jpg',name:'Abba', address: 
                     '3 Vecq st', }]});//setState
    }//componentWillMount



    reOrder(orderBy, orderDir) {
        this.setState({
            orderBy: orderBy,
            orderDir: orderDir,
        });//setState
    }//reorder

    render(){
        var tenants = this.state.tenants;
        var orderBy = this.state.orderBy;
        var orderDir = this.state.orderDir;

        tenants = _.orderBy(tenants, function(item) {
            return item[orderBy].toLowerCase();
        }, orderDir);//orderBy

        tenants = tenants.map(function(item, index){
            return (
                <TenantList key = { index } singleTenant = { item } />
             )
        }.bind(this))

        return(
            <div style={styles.root}>
                <Subheader>Payment Status</Subheader>

                <PaymentStatus/>
                <SearchTenant
                    orderBy = { this.state.orderBy }
                    orderDir = { this.state.orderDir }
                    onReOrder = { this.reOrder }
                />
                <GridList cols={1} cellHeight={80} style={styles.gridList}>
                    {tenants}
                </GridList>
            </div>

        )//return
    }//render
}
```

**childcomponent**

```
export default class SearchTenant extends Component {
    handleSort(e){
        this.props.onReOrder(e.target.id, this.props.orderDir)
    }//handleSort

    handleOrder(e){
        this.props.onReOrder(this.props.orderBy, e.target.id)
    }//handleSort


    render(){
       return(
           <div className="input-group">
               <input placeholder="Search" type="text" onChange = { 
                this.handleSearch }  className= "validate"/>
               <DropDownMenu openImmediately={true}>
                   <MenuItem id = "name" onClick = {this.handleSort}>Name{ ( 
                        this.props.orderBy === 'name') ? <i 
                        className="material-icons">check_circle</i>: null }
                   </MenuItem>
                   <MenuItem id = "address" onClick = 
                       {this.handleSort}>Address{ 
                       (this.props.orderBy === 'address') ? <i 
                       className="material-
                       icons">check_circle</i>: null }
                   </MenuItem>
                   <MenuItem id = "asc" onClick = {this.handleOrder}>Asc{ 
                       (this.props.orderDir === 'asc') ? <i 
                       className="material-icons">check_circle</i>: null }
                   </MenuItem>
                   <MenuItem id = "desc" onClick = {this.handleOrder}>Desc{ 
                       (this.props.orderDir === 'desc') ? <i 
                        className="material-icons">check_circle</i>: null }
                   </MenuItem>
               </DropDownMenu>
           </div>
       )//return
    }//render
}//TeamList
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to ensure that you are binding the functions you pass to inline event handlers properly in order for the calls inside them to be able to reference `this` of the component scope correctly:

Define the following constructor in your component:

```
constructor (props){
  super (props):
  this.handleSort = this.handleSort.bind(this);
  this.handleOrder = this.handleOrder.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: I get another error after binding (Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined). It comes from this code on my parent component             
  tenants = _.orderBy(tenants, function(item) {
            return item[orderBy].toLowerCase();
        }, orderDir);//orderBy.  do you know what the reason might be

Comment: item[orderBy] is resolving to undefined.

Comment: Have you tried debugging what `item[orderBy]` resolves to?

Comment: it resolves my data at the beginning but when i click on the menu item it resolves to undefined.

Comment: It's difficult to tell, might be worth adding this as another question and add the code of the parent component.

Comment: ok thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the `this` you are referring to inside `handleSort` and `handleOrder` is not referring to component's this instead it is referring to the internal methods this.

There a re two solutions for this problem.

Either bind the function with component's this inside the component's constructor:

```
export default class SearchTenant extends Component {

    constructor() {
        this.handleSort = this.handleSort.bind(this)
        this.handleOrder = this.handleOrder.bind(this)
    }

    // rest of the code
}
```

Or use ES6's [arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) function which provides lexical scoping:

```
export default class SearchTenant extends Component {

    handleSort = () => {
        this.props.onReOrder(e.target.id, this.props.orderDir)
    }
}
```